# How can I power up my Arduino Nano for project of Rocket Data logging?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

I am building a Model Rocket for which I need arduino nano to log data.But,I dont know how to power it up once it goes off the ground.Can anyone explain?

Comment: How about a lithium battery?  They are very light and have enough voltage (~4 V)

Comment: Yup,I heard of them but real problem is I really don't know anything.I am absolute beginner.Can you help me ?Can you help me how to connect battery and arduino either nano or micro or esp8266?I need to consider weight factor also to lift the rocket.So,with minimum weight and maximum efficiency which is better?